# How to reduce top padding in UILabel

Tags: ios, uilabel

I designed a **UIViewController** which contains a **UILabel** using Interface Builder - Storyboard -

I notice there is a lot of space - padding - in top of UILabel, how to reduce this space - padding - using Storyboard, or even code.

Comment: looking for this: [uilabel sizeToFit];?

Comment: i said that first... I will add it as an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were looking for this:

```
[UILabel sizeToFit];
```

Answer (score 3):

you can call `sizeToFit` on a label to lay it according to the size required by the text

---

any other 'padding' would be from the font.

the label itself doesn't apply any other padding